# MVC model binding to interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, interface, dependency-injection, model-binding

I have created an **OrderFormViewModel** which looks something like

```
public class OrderFormViewModel 
{
    public IOrderDetails { get; set; }
    public IDeliveryDetails { get; set; }
    public IPaymentDetails { get; set; }
    // ... etc

    public SelectList DropDownOptions { get; set; }
    // ... etc

}
```

This goes to my **Create** view, where each section (i.e. delivery details, payment details... etc) is then passed to a partial view which captures the necessary fields.

I thought this was all quite neat until I ran it and realized of course that the MVC model binder doesn't know how to instantiate any of the interfaces.

Is there a way to resolve this somehow?

I'm also trying to learn DI using the Unity container, so I'm trying to avoid having references to any concrete classes in my UI project (model is in a separate project).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to make a custom model binder, but this path means you will need to go through the effort of translating form elements to properties on your object. However, you have complete control over which implementation of IOrderDetails gets used, for example, or you can have your DI give you the right concrete type using it's configuration.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution might be here (under Interface Binding Filter vs View Model Binding):
http://codetunnel.com/aspnet-mvc-model-binding-security/

Comment: That's an interesting blog post. It's a pretty out there idea, but certainly clever too.